# Is the leading order contribution to the double-trace operator anomalous dimension always $O(1/N^2)$?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, ads-cft, large-n

Is the leading order contribution to the double-trace operator anomalous dimension always $O(1/N^2)$ ? I noticed that the double-trace contribution in Polchinski's paper [hep-th/0907.0151](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.0151) gets an anomalous dimension at $O(1/N^2)$. Is this true for any large-N CFT? If so, how to prove it? Are there counter-examples?